# Regex: seeing/finding AB as distinct from AB-C

Tags: r, regex

In `R` I need to search a character vector as shown below.  I need to return "AB" separately from "ABC" so I am using word-boundaries.  However, I also need to find "AB-C" as something distinct from "AB"; there are some questions along these lines here but I can't get the proper invocation.  Put another way, I need each of these strings to be found uniquely as I loop over them, and my grep expression needs to always return a single answer.

```
vec <- c("AB", "ABC", "AB-C")
grep("\\bAB\\b", vec) # 1 + 3, but only want 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just specify the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string

```
grep("^AB$", vec)
#[1] 1
```